# How to style appcompat v7 Toolbar to look like v4

Tags: android, android-layout, android-styles

I have started with Android navigation drawer https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html and then added v7 support lib. Everything works fine and I know Google says this is "new better" way. But is there any easy way to get v4 "retro" look with v7?

Comment: Add a `Toolbar` and just make it look the way you want.

Comment: Change the theme back to what you used on legacy

Comment: @Robert Rowntree I used dark Holo, but with v7 I was "forced" to apply AppCompat theme. Did I miss something?